# Common/separated ground in dummy load?

Tags: ground

I've got 2 circuits:

1. MCU with DAC, ADC and another 3.3 V electronics:

[image]

2. Dummy load (Max 24 VDC):

[image]

Do I need to connect two separate grounds (MCU ground and dummy load ground) into common ground?

I think yes, still not certain about it -- I don't know the impact on the accuracy of the measurements taken by ADC.

If no, where should I ground the R's and D's - to the MCU ground or dummy load ground?
If you have any remarks on this circuit feel free to criticize me.

Comment: What is the purpose of R and Zener in your circuit?

Comment: When the voltage exceeds the maximum limit eg. 24V the zener makes the short circuit to GND.
R's are here because of the voltage divider - 24V could harm 3.3V logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the grounds should be connected together, otherwise you don't know what your Vgs on the MOSFET is.  You have a bigger problem, however, because your power resistor is on the wrong side of your MOSFET.  You should be doing low-side switching, otherwise you will not be getting your gate voltage high enough over your source voltage.